# How do I search the columns value in another Excel?

Tags: sql, excel

I have inserted value from Excel into SQL and some of the rows are missing in SQL. Both have Staffid which is unique field. 
Some of the rows from excel are missing in SQL , in excel its 4011 and in SQL its 3996. Checking one by one is a lengthy job. So I exported SQL onto the excel. Now I want to match Staffid in original with the Staffid in SQL's excel.
I tried vlookup, this returned #N/A even if the value was present in SQLs. I tried Match function but it returned some numbers.

So is there any simple way to find missing staffid in SQL's Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution 
I sorted both columns in alphabetic order and used formula

> =if(A1=B1,"True", "False")

This returned false where the data didn't match , had to work a bit but eventually sorted.